# ssh with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty

Tags: ssh, sudo, io-redirection, tty

#### Problem

Consider a command like this:

```
<binary_input ssh user@server 'sudo tool' >binary_output 2>error.log
```

where `tool` is arbitrary and `ssh` is a wrapper or some `ssh-like-contraption` that allows the above to work. With regular `ssh` it doesn't work.

I used `sudo` here but it's just an *example* of a command that requires tty. I'd like a general solution, not specific to `sudo`.

---

#### Research: the cause

With regular `ssh` it doesn't work because:

- `sudo` needs tty to ask for password ([or to work at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616/108618)), so I need [`ssh -t`](https://superuser.com/a/117875/432690); actually in this case I need `ssh -tt`.
- On the other hand `ssh -tt` will make `sudo` read the password from `binary_input`. I want to provide the password via my local tty. Even if `sudo` is configured to work without password or if I inject the password to the `binary_input`, `ssh -tt` will make `sudo` and `tool` read from the remote tty and write output *and* errors and prompts to the remote tty. Not only I won't be able to tell the output and the errors/prompts apart locally. All the streams will be processed by the remote tty and this will mangle data (you can see this in some examples in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1735624/432690), in the section entitled "Some practice").

---

#### Research: comparison to commands that work

- This local command is the reference point. Let's assume it successfully processes some binary data:

  ```
  <binary_input tool >binary_output
  ```
- If I need to run `tool` on a server, I can do this. [Even if `ssh` asks for my password](https://superuser.com/a/1557724/432690), this will work:

  ```
  <binary_input ssh user@server tool >binary_output
  ```

  In this case `ssh` is transparent for binary data.
- Similarly local `sudo` can be transparent. The following command won't mangle the data even if `sudo` asks for my password:

  ```
  <binary_input sudo tool >binary_output
  ```
- But running `tool` on the server with `sudo` is troublesome:

  ```
  <binary_input ssh user@server 'sudo tool' >binary_output
  ```

  In this configuration `ssh` and `sudo` *together* cannot be transparent in general. Finding a way to make them transparent is the gist of this question.

---

#### Research: similar questions

I have found few similar questions:

- [Use `sudo` with `ssh` command and capturing stdout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158208/108618)

  This question cares about stdout only. The existing answer (from the author of the question) advises `sudo -S` which consumes stdin. I don't really want to alter my `binary_input`. And I would appreciate a solution not specific to `sudo`.
- [stderr over `ssh -t`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134139/108618)

  This concentrates on passing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and the background is GNU `parallel`. A workaround that only makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> work without a remote tty is not enough for me.
- [SSH: Provide additional “pipe” fds in addition to stdin, stdout, stderr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226638/108618)

  This is a good start (especially [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226794/108618), I think). However here I want to emphasize the need for tty. I want a solution that automates things and allows me to use remote `sudo` (or whatever) as if it was local.

---

#### My explicit question

In the following command:

```
<binary_input ssh user@server 'requires-tty' >binary_output 2>error.log
```

`requires-tty` is a placeholder for code that requires a tty but processes binary data from its stdin to its stdout. It seems I need `ssh -tt`, otherwise `requires-tty` will not work; and at the same time I mustn't use `ssh -tt`, otherwise the binary data will be mangled. How can I solve this problem in a convenient way?

`requires-tty` can be `sudo …` but I don't want a solution specific to `sudo`.

I imagine the ideal(?) solution will be a script/tool that replaces `ssh` in the above invocation and just works. It should(?) connect the remote stdin, stdout and stderr each to its local counterpart, *and* the remote tty to the local tty.

If it's possible, I prefer a client-side solution that does not require any server-side companion program.

Comment: Note: I created this self-answered question because a fellow user asked me to publish my work.

Comment: What a great resource, thank you!

Comment: Related: [Why do I need a tty to run sudo if I can sudo without a password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616) (where my answer shows an approach using `expect` or `script`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Script

I'm the author of the question and this is my attempt to build a script that solves the problem. The script is intended to work on the client side, it replaces `ssh` in the command in question. It's **experimental**. I call it `sshe`. This is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -

# the name of the script
me="${0##*/}"

# error handling functions
scream() { printf '%s\n' >&2 "$1"; }
die()    { scream "$2"; exit "$1"; }

# initialization of variables
redir0=''
redir1=''
redir2=''
tty="/dev/$(ps -p "$$" -o tty=)"

# edge cases
[ "$tty" = '/dev/?' ] && { scream "$me: no tty detected, falling back to regular ssh"
   exec ssh "$@"; }
[ "$#" -lt 2 ] && die 1 "usage: $me [options] [user@]hostname command"

# see what needs to be redirected
exec 7>&1
if [ "$(<&0 tty 2>/dev/null)" != "$tty" ]; then redir0=y; fi
if [ "$(<&7 tty 2>/dev/null)" != "$tty" ]; then redir1=y; fi
if [ "$(<&2 tty 2>/dev/null)" != "$tty" ]; then redir2=y; fi
exec 7>&-

# edge case
[ "$redir0$redir1$redir2" ] || { scream "$me: no redirection detected, falling back to ssh -t"
   exec ssh -t "$@"; }

# command line parsing, extract two last arguments: ... host command
z="$#"
n="$z"
for arg do
   if [ "$n" -eq "$z" ]; then
      set --
   fi
   case "$n" in
      1) command="$arg"
   ;;
      2) host="$arg"
   ;;
      *)
      set -- "$@" "$arg"
   esac
   n="$(($n - 1))"
done

# prepare to clean on exit
trap 'status="$?"; rm -r "$tmpd" 2>/dev/null; trap - EXIT; exit "$status"' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM

# temporary directory and socket
tmpd="$(mktemp -d)"
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] || exit 1
sock="$tmpd/sock"

# main pipe: ssh master connection -> background cat
(
[ "$redir0" ] || exec 0</dev/null
# ssh master connection, it will report the remote PID of the remote shell via its stdout
ssh -M -S "$sock" "$@" -T "$host" '</dev/null echo "$$"; exec sleep 2147483647'
) | {

# read the remote PID
IFS= read -r rpid || exit 1

# background process to pass data
exec 6<&0
cat <&6 2>/dev/null &

# move original descriptors out of the way
exec </dev/tty >/dev/tty 6>&-

# prepare remote redirections
if [ "$redir0" ]; then redir0="<&6";  fi
if [ "$redir1" ]; then redir1=">&7";  fi
if [ "$redir2" ]; then redir2="2>&8"; fi

# ssh to run the command, with remote tty
ssh -S "$sock" -t "$host" "
 trap 'status=\"\$?\"; kill $rpid 2>/dev/null; trap - EXIT; exit \"\$status\"' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM
 exec 6</proc/$rpid/fd/0 7>/proc/$rpid/fd/1 8>/proc/$rpid/fd/2 9>/dev/tty $redir0 $redir1 $redir2 || exit 3;
 $command"
}
```

---

#### General disclaimer

- The script works well in many cases. I *don't* mean it fails randomly. It doesn't fail randomly. I *don't* mean it cannot handle some specific data. It handles arbitrary data.

  Cases when it "doesn't work well" arise from its interaction with the local tty only. Data (including arbitrary binary data) that flows via channels not including any tty is always fine. Please read the rest of this answer, especially the "Obstacles and caveats" section, to understand the problem and to learn what to avoid.
- A command like this:

  ```
  <binary_input sshe user@server 'sudo tool' >binary_output 2>error.log
  ```

  avoids the problem. It should work fine, if only the technical requirements are met (see "Requirements" below).
- The script is experimental and I tried to set `trap`s, to preserve exit status and to clean on exit in a sane(?) way. I'm not sure if I succeeded.
- The script was never intended to be foolproof. Treat it as a proof of concept.

---

#### Usage

Use `sshe` like this:

```
sshe … [user@]hostname command
```

where `…` denotes options you would use if the executable was `ssh`. There's no need to put `-t` nor `-tt` (nor `-T`) here. The script assumes you want tty on the remote side (otherwise just use `ssh`). The script *expects* at least one of the local stdin, stdout, stderr to be redirected away from the local tty. The script will fall back to `ssh -t` if everything is connected to the local tty.

**Important** things:

- `command` is the shell code you want to run on the server. It *must* be a single argument, the very last argument to `sshe`. It cannot be omitted.
- `hostname` or `user@hostname` must be the second to last argument. It cannot be omitted.

Internally the script needs to know the `command` to add some code in front. It needs to know `[user@]hostname` because it uses it twice. The script just picks the last and the second to last argument respectively, hence the above limitations.

Not every valid `ssh` invocation can be converted to `sshe` invocation by just replacing `ssh` with `sshe`. But I believe any valid `ssh` invocation that runs code (as opposed to spawning an interactive shell) can be rearranged to be a valid `sshe` command. Example:

```
ssh user@server -p 1234 echo foo
```

should be rearranged to:

```
sshe -p 1234 user@server 'echo foo'
```

(except you don't really need `sshe` in *this* case; it's just an example of the right syntax). If you used `sshe user@server -p 1234 echo foo` then the script will take `echo` as the server and `foo` as the command because it does not parse its arguments like `ssh` would.

There are examples down below.

---

#### Requirements, portability issues

Local requirements (where `sshe` runs):

- `/dev/$(ps -p "$$" -o tty=)` assumed to be the "real name" of the controlling terminal. Compare [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187319/108618).
- `mktemp -d`.
- `ssh` supporting `-M` and `-S`; the script creates master and slave connections.

Remote requirements (on the server):

- SSH server able to handle master and slave connections.
- `/proc` pseudo-filesystem.
- Ability to use `/proc/nnnn/fd/N` of another process that belongs to the same user.
- POSIX-compliant shell.
- Silent startup scripts (compare [*SCP doesn't work when `echo` in `.bashrc`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442753/10765659), with `sshe` the situation is similar)
  .

During my tests I successfully connected from Kubuntu (18.04.5 LTS) to various Debian or Debian-derivative servers. My `ssh` and `sshd` are from OpenSSH.

---

#### Operation

`sshe` (unless it decides to fall back to `ssh` or to `ssh -t`) runs `ssh` twice:

1. `ssh -M … -T …` is a master connection that does not allocate tty on the remote side. The shell code it runs there reports its PID via stdout and `exec`s to a long-running `sleep` (about 68 years). The standard file descriptors of this process will be used by another process(es).

   The PID reported from the master `ssh` is picked up by `read`. After this the stdout of the master `ssh` will go to a background `cat` whose sole purpose is to relay it to the (local) stdout of `sshe`.
2. Later `ssh … -t …` is a slave connection that does allocate tty on the remote side. Already knowing the remote PID from the master connection, it sets up redirections, so code supplied to `sshe` as `command` can use separate stdin, stdout, stderr (via the master `ssh` connection) and tty (via the slave `ssh` connection) on the remote side. The slave `ssh` does not use the original stdin nor stdout of `sshe`, it uses the local `/dev/tty` instead.

The idea is similar to what [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226794/108618) (already linked to in the question) does. The code in the linked answer runs `ssh` (implicit `ssh -T`) twice to provide additional descriptors. My script runs `ssh -T` and `ssh -t` to provide standard descriptors and tty. And it uses the master-slave functionality of `ssh`, so it authenticates (e.g. asks for password) once.

If none of the local stdin, stdout, stderr is the local tty then this is how data flows:

- Local stdin goes to the master `ssh`, no other local process reads from the stdin of the script. By reading from (remote) `/proc/nnnn/fd/0` remote processes can access the local stdin. The slave `ssh` connection prepends redirections to the `command`, so the shell on the remote side uses `/proc/nnnn/fd/0` as its stdin.
- Similarly the shell on the remote side uses `/proc/nnnn/fd/1` as its stdout. Whatever goes there will come out of the local master `ssh`. This is after the master `ssh` retrieved the right PID from (remote) shell code it run. The PID was consumed by `read`, any data that follows goes to the original stdout of `sshe` via the background `cat`.
- Similarly the shell on the remote side uses `/proc/nnnn/fd/2` as its stderr. The stream will come directly from the local master `ssh` to the stderr of `sshe`. Some local processes spawned by the script use the stderr of the script as their stderr, so if you do `sshe … 2>error.log` then the log will contain their error messages as well. In particular expect `Shared connection to server closed.`. This is similar to `ssh -T … 2>error.log` where the log gathers messages from remote command(s) and from the `ssh` itself. I think it's possible to make a variant of `sshe` that will pass stderr from remote commands via a channel associated with stdout of yet another `ssh`; in this case one will be able to tell apart the remote stderr from diagnostic messages generated by local tools. The script does not do this though.
- The local tty is available for the master `ssh` (if it needs to ask for password) and then for the slave `ssh`. (Frankly more local tools used by the script have access to the local `/dev/tty`, they just don't use it.) The slave `ssh -t` uses `/dev/tty` as its stdin and stdout. This way it connects the local and the remote `/dev/tty` despite other redirections (like `ssh -t` run in a terminal without redirections would). Remote processes reading from their `/dev/tty` will get what the local slave `ssh` reads from the local `/dev/tty`. Remote processes writing to their `/dev/tty` will make the local slave `ssh` write to the local `/dev/tty`.

If the local stdin, stdout or stderr is the local tty then its respective counterpart on the remote side (for `command` run remotely by the slave `ssh`) will not be redirected to `/proc/nnnn/fd/N` and it will stay connected to the remote tty. It would get to the local tty either way. The point is it should not bypass the remote tty. The reason for this will be clear in a moment.

There are few local and remote redirections not necessarily required for `sshe` to work. It's because of my other experimental things. I decided to keep the extra redirections, just in case they are more important to the sole `sshe` than I remember.

---

#### Obstacles and caveats

The whole concept is not as easy as it may seem. A tty can process what you type (e.g. [translate `^M` into `^J`](https://superuser.com/a/1648043/432690)) and what is about to be printed (e.g. if I `cat` a file with *nix line endings to the terminal, each newline character will work like carriage_return + newline). Invoke [`stty -a`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) to see plenty of settings.

This is why you don't want tty when processing arbitrary binary data. And you do want it when interacting.

Processes can configure the tty so it meets their needs. See [*raw* vs *cooked*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21760/108618).

When you `ssh` in a way so tty is allocated on the server, the processes there will see it as their tty. If they need to configure their tty, they will configure the tty they see on the server. They have no means to directly configure the local tty of `ssh`. All(?) the "cooking" is done by the remote tty and `ssh` configures the local tty so it does not interfere.

This is the reason `sshe` should not bypass the remote tty when redirecting remote descriptors that ultimately should be connected to the local tty. If the remote tty is bypassed then there will be no entity to "cook" the stream. By connecting the stdin, stdout or stderr of `sshe` to the local tty you indicate you want it "cooked". This makes `sshe` similar to `ssh … command` run in an interactive shell, i.e. the case where all the standard streams are "cooked" by the local tty (note this `ssh` is like `ssh -T` and it does not place the local terminal in "raw" mode).

So `sshe` "cooks" what apparently you want to be "cooked". A problem occurs when you do something like this:

```
sshe … command | whatever
```

Data will flow from remote `command` to local `whatever` without being "cooked" (as one would expect from `ssh … command | whatever`) but the output of `whatever` will not be "cooked" locally. `sshe` could reconfigure the local tty so it "cooks", but if the `command` happens to print to its tty (i.e. to the remote tty that may or may not "cook", depending on its settings) then the local tty should not "cook".

`sshe` does not try to solve this. It's basically intended to support cases where the ultimate output goes to somewhere else than the terminal (e.g. to a regular file or to a block device). The following code is better in this matter:

```
sshe … command | whatever >some_file
```

although stderr from `whatever` won't be "cooked". Expect diagnostic messages to *look* weird. Note you can redirect them to a file (or to another local tty that will "cook" them).

It's even worse on the input end. If another local process tries to read from the local tty, it will not only read raw data, it will compete with `sshe` for the input. This is a general problem of two processes reading from the same terminal.

To summarize: build a local command (pipeline), so only (a single) `sshe` wants to read from the local tty; do not let tools other than `sshe` print to the local tty, unless you can stand "raw" output.

I developed `sshe` to be able to pass or process binary data. In my case there's hardly ever a need to read data from the local tty or to write data to the local tty. I can stand diagnostic messages from local tools not "cooked" enough. In return `sshe` allows me to use remote `sudo` as if it was local.

---

#### Examples

- Reading from or writing to a remote block device that needs `sudo` access.

  - Reading:

    ```
    sshe user@server 'sudo cat /dev/sdx1' >local_file
    # or
    sshe user@server 'sudo pv  /dev/sdx1' >local_file
    ```
  - Writing:

    ```
    <local_file sshe user@server 'sudo tee /dev/sdx1 >/dev/null'
    ```

    In my tests local `pv` apparently doesn't mind the local tty being "raw"; or rather the configuration it imposes and the configuration `sshe` imposes are not(?) contradictory and it doesn't(?) matter which tool configures the local tty first. So this seems to work:

    ```
    pv local_file | sshe user@server 'sudo tee /dev/sdx1 >/dev/null'
    ```

    Note if settings from `pv` disturbed `sshe` then you might not be able to supply password to the remote `sudo`. If settings from `sshe` disturbed `pv` then what `pv` prints to the terminal might look mangled. Even in these hypothetical cases the content of `local_file` will get to the remote `/dev/sdx1` verbatim.
- Local `sudo` and remote `sudo` together.

  If local `sudo` is going to ask for your password, `sudo … | sshe … 'sudo …'` or `sshe … 'sudo …' | sudo …` is not a good idea because the local `sudo` and `sshe` will both read from the local tty at the same time. Totally local `sudo … | sudo …` works because `sudo` implements a locking mechanism, so two local `sudo`s don't interact with the same terminal simultaneously. This won't work with a mixture of local and remote `sudo`s.

  Hopefully your local `sudo` [allows timeout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416055/108618). If so, invoke `sudo -v` beforehand to supply the local password (if needed) without interference; then go with a pipe:

  - Copying from a remote device to a local device:

    ```
    sudo -v   # input local password if needed
    sshe user@server 'sudo cat /dev/sdx1' | sudo tee /dev/sdy1 >/dev/null
    ```
  - Copying from a local device to a remote device:

    ```
    sudo -v   # input local password if needed
    sudo cat /dev/sdy1 | sshe user@server 'sudo tee /dev/sdx1 >/dev/null'
    ```
- Exactly what the question requested.

  - With `sudo`:

    ```
    <binary_input sshe user@server 'sudo tool' >binary_output 2>error.log
    ```
  - Or more generally:

    ```
    <binary_input sshe user@server 'requires-tty' >binary_output 2>error.log
    ```

---

#### Final note

I used to think tunneling stdin to stdin, stdout to stdout, stderr to stderr *and* `/dev/tty` to `/dev/tty` is trivial. I used to wonder why `ssh` doesn't provide an option (similar to `-t`) to do it. Now I know it's not that simple; and I suspect *maybe* I'm still missing something.

Comment: `[ -e /dev/tty ]` doesn't test for the presence of a controlling terminal, just whether that device file exists are not. Since you already do `ps -p "$$" -o tty=`, you can check that against `?` to check if there's a controlling terminal.

Comment: linked ticket https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3542