# How to use sudo privileges when copying files from one machine to another via ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

Ok, so I already know how to copy a file in my machine to another one, and when I do it, (I'm trying to copy it to a sudo protected directory) it says permission denied. I do not know where to put the sudo so it isn't in my machine but it doesn't get in the way of the directory. Here's what I normally type:

```
scp /Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/script.py pi@192.168.x.xx:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sudo dd` like:

```
ssh user@host 'sudo dd of="/remote/path/to/file"' < "/local/path/to/file"
```

or use `rsync`:

```
rsync -av -e ssh --rsync-path="sudo rsync" "/local/path/to/file" user@host:"/remote/path/to/"
```

Comment: I don't know `rsync` but I can tell something about the first command: (1) `/remote/path/to/file` is quoted locally but not in the remote shell; some paths may be misinterpreted, possibly badly. (2) `tee` will unnecessarily print its input, ultimately to the local terminal; in general the input file may be big and/or binary. (3) `sudo` may ask for password or require tty anyway; see [this question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618) for some insight. My point is the first command will work in fortunate circumstances, but in less fortunate it may wreak havoc.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the headsup! I updated the answer.