# Why is stdin input replacing or corrupting my variables when running a script using SSH?

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdin, subshell

GNU bash, version 4.3.27

I'm running into an odd issue with a script that writes output to a file. The script ssh's to a list of servers and records the state/substate of a few services. I then store the results in an array.

If I type into the console window while its running however, the input gets stored into the array `$result_arr` and I don't know why

```
#!/bin/bash


check_services()
{
  server_number="$1"
  local result
  local result_arr
  local error_flag="OK"

  #Get service status
  result=$(ssh server.$host -t "$cmds_services")

  #trim carriage returns if present
  result=$(echo "$result" | tr -d '\r')

  #split result into array by line
  readarray -t result_arr <<<"$result" 

  echo "$server_number,${result_arr[0]},${result_arr[1]},${result_arr[2]},${result_arr[3]},${result_arr[4]},${result_arr[5]},${result_arr[6]},${result_arr[7]}" >> "$OUTFILE"
}

main()
{
  for server in $(cat /home/data/serverlist)
  do
    clear -x
    echo "Gathering Data...Server $server"
    check_services "$server"
  done

}
```

When I spam 'a' and enter while the script runs, `$OUTFILE` will look something like this:

```
1234,active,mounted,active,mounted,a,,a,a
```

instead of

```
1234,active,mounted,active,mounted,active,mounted,active,mounted
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "_When I spam 'a' and enter while the script runs_"? To me, spam is stuff that's unwanted

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I do not need it, sorry was leftover from some previous work. I've removed it and that seems to have fixed it. I'm going to test some more. Im possibly more confused now!

Comment: as an aside, you could use `readarray -t result_arr < <( ssh ... | tr -d '\r')` to do without the intermediate mangling by echo and the command substitution (the latter would remove trailing empty lines). Those CRs you get are also possibly due to `ssh -t`, try e.g. `ssh -t localhost echo foo |od -c` and the same without -t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you used `ssh -t`. The `-t` option allocates a tty on the remote side.

When the remote command works, the remote tty is most likely in a mode where it echoes the input. It's like when you locally run `cat` and type to it, you see the input echoed by the tty (not by `cat`) and only upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> `cat` reads it and prints as its output.

In your case the remote tty echoes what your local `ssh` reads from its stdin. This is then captured by `result=$(ssh …)` along with the "real" output of the remote commands.

If you don't need a remote tty, do not pass `-t` to `ssh`.

If you do need a remote tty, pass `-t` but don't let `ssh` read from the local stdin: `</dev/null ssh -t …`. Note you won't be able to type to the remote command at all.

If you do need a remote tty and you do need to pass (type) something from the local stdin to the remote command, pass `-t`, do not redirect stdin to `/dev/null`, but tell the remote tty to turn off its echo. You do this by adding `stty -echo;` to the beginning of your `$cmds_services`. You don't need to turn echo on (with `stty echo`) at the end because the remote tty will be destroyed anyway. Note any of the commands in `$cmds_services` may reconfigure the tty; depending on the command, you may or may not be able to prevent this.

In a really demanding case you may find this question of mine useful: [*`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618). Even if you don't need it, you can get some insight from it, from my answer there and from links therein.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for taking the time to write that out.

Comment: and `ssh -t` likely disables the echo on the _local_ terminal which you'd usually get, and which is why it's hard to _see_ the difference when just running `ssh` vs `ssh -t` interactively